# Can Python Selenium run in Debian?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, debian

I'm trying to using Python Selenium in Debian.

Here is my simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions ()
chrome_options.add_argument ("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path='/var/qa/chromedriver')

driver.get ('https://getbootstrap.com/')
```

My question is can I run python selenium in Debian and how to solve this issue.

Thank you so much!